# Deployment from unity to Hololens 2 giving error DEP6957

Tags: unity-game-engine, deployment, hololens

### Goal:

Deploying an application from Unity to Hololens 2

---

### Problem:

Yesterday every deployment i did worked correctly. But today when i tried to deploy a new version of my application to the hololens I'm getting the following error.
([Picture with the error i receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEvqs.png))
My build was succesfull but the deployment not.

In the following image you see the settings i used for the deployment. My machine name is the IP address of the hololens.
([Settings to deploy to hololens2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJFNt.png)). I also enabled the developer settings on the device itself.

---

I already shut down the hololens en tried again to deploy but this didn't work either. I created a new build but that was not the solution.

---

Do any of you know what I need to do to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it able to deploy the app through a USB cable?

Comment: And what's your unity version?

Comment: My Unity version is 2020.3.17f1

Comment: We recommend you use [Unity 2020.3.31f1 with the latest Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version#unity-20203-lts-recommended) to develop the Hololens app. And is it able to deploy your app through USB cable?

Comment: Yeah, in the mean time I'm able to deploy throught USB cable. But still not over WIFI, So right now i keep deploying with cable

Comment: OK. Please also check if your IP address is correct and if you install your app with the device portal.

Comment: I set everything corerct. The correct ip, architect on arm64, release.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to your project property window -> debugging -> Machine name. Click the dropdown button, and select `<Locate...>`
[image]

In the next pop-up window, you should see the HoloLens in your network, select it and click the Select button.
[image]

Then try deploy your app again.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue and selecting it did not work. I had to type in the IP address into the machine name field. Using the hostname did not work (despite it detecting the device just fine via the hostname in the Remote Connection window)